# Rails 4, select tag onchange event failed to trigger json on form_tag

Tags: javascript, html, json, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I am writing a simple web site that requires cascade select tags. The selected option in the first select tag, floor_id, changes the options in the second select tag, space_id. I have put these 2 selects into 2 separated forms. The problem is, the onchange event in the select floor_id does not trigger the json changing the options in the second select tag but the submit button does. Could some gurus tell me how to fix it? Thanks a ton!

Here is my code in app/controllers/spaces_controller.rb

```
class SpacesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @floors = Floor.all.order(:name)
        @spaces = Space.all.order(:name)
    end

    def list
        @floor_id = params[:floor_id]
        @spaces = Space.includes(:maps).where( \
            "maps.floor_id = ? OR 0 = char_length(?)", \
                @floor_id.to_i, \
                @floor_id.to_s, \
            ).references(:map)
        render :partial => 'list', :object => @spaces
    end
...
end
```

File app/assets/javascripts/spaces.js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#category").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("#space_list").html xhr.responseText
  ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("#space_list").html "<option value=''>Error</option>"
```

File app/assets/javascripts/defaults.js

```
function go_to_uri
  ( iObject
  , iId
  , iAction
  )
{
  if (!iId || iId.length === 0 || iId === "" || typeof iId == 'undefined' || !/[^\s]/.test(iId) || /^\s*$/.test(iId) || iId.replace(/\s/g,"") == "")
  return false;
  this.document.location.href = iObject + "/" + iId + "/" + iAction;
  return false;
}
```

File app/views/spaces/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Spaces</h1>
<%= form_tag list_spaces_url, method: :post, remote: true, id: 'category' do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :floor_id, 'Floor' %>
    <%= select_tag \
      :floor_id, \
      options_from_collection_for_select(@floors, :id, :name), \
      include_blank: true, \
      onchange: '$(this).parent(\'form\').submit();' %>
  </p>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag 'nil', method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag :space, 'Space' %>
  <span id="space_list"><%= render 'list' %></span>
  <%= button_tag type: \
    'button', \
    onclick: 'go_to_uri("spaces", this.form.space.value, "map")' \
    do %>
      Show Map
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

file app/views/spaces/list.html.erb

```
<%= select_tag \
  :space_id, \
  options_from_collection_for_select(@spaces, :id, :name), \
  include_blank: true, \
  onchange: 'go_to_uri("spaces", this.value, "map")' %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewrote the onchange event with coffee script and now it is working.

File app/assets/javascripts/spaces.js.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#space_category").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("#space_list").html xhr.responseText
  ).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
    $("#space_list").html "<option value=''>Error</option>"
  $(".space_category").change ->
    $("#space_category").submit()
```

File app/views/spaces/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Spaces</h1>
<%= form_tag list_spaces_url, method: :post, remote: true, id: 'space_category' do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= label_tag :floor_id, 'Floor' %>
    <%= select_tag \
      :floor_id, \
      options_from_collection_for_select(@floors, :id, :name), \
      include_blank: true, \
      class: 'space_catefory' %>
  </p>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag 'nil', method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag :space, 'Space' %>
  <span id="space_list"><%= render 'list' %></span>
  <%= button_tag type: \
    'button', \
    onclick: 'go_to_uri("spaces", this.form.space.value, "map")' \
    do %>
      Show Map
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```